# this error comes when i install qbitorrent and vlc

Tags: software-installation

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libfreerdp-client1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libfreerdp-core1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libfreerdp-gdi1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles2
       Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvncclient1 (>= 0.9.10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Conflicts: vlc:i386 but 2.1.4-1 is to be installed
 vlc:i386 : Depends: vlc-nox:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libaa1:i386 (>= 1.4p5) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcaca0:i386 (>= 0.99.beta17-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libfribidi0:i386 (>= 0.19.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                     libgl1:i386
            Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsdl-image1.2:i386 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libtar0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libva-x11-1:i386 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libva1:i386 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libvlccore7:i386 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcb-composite0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcb-keysyms1:i386 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcb-randr0:i386 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcb-shm0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcb-xv0:i386 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxpm4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not installable
            Conflicts: vlc but 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Have you tried what `apt-get` is telling you: "`Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages`"?

Comment: yes Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qbittorrent : Depends: libboost-system1.62.0 but it is not installable
               Depends:e
@MrShunz

Comment: but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install vlc
```

these commands in sequence as desсribed should work.

P.S.: Just checked on my eOS 0.4.1 - simply works.

Comment: It shows that E: error ,pkg problemResolver:resolve generated breaks,this may be caused by held packages

Comment: have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/129040

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but a workaround in case nothing else works:

You can also install VLC via [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/vlc) and [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.videolan.VLC) and qBittorrent via [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent).

Still, something seems to be seriously wrong with your system, so you should try to fix it instead of just ignoring it. Hopefully other people can help you find a solution for it.